# Why does function behavior used within pandas apply change?

Tags: python, string, pandas, int, dataframe

I cannot figure out why a simple function:

```
def to_integer(value):
    if value == "":
        return None
    return int(value)
```

changes values from `str` to `int` only if there's no empty string `""` in the dataframe, i.e. only if no value is to be returned as `None`.

If I go:

```
type(to_integer('1')) == int
```

returns True.

Now, using `apply` and `to_integer` with `df1`:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(['1', '2', '3'], columns=['integer'])
result = df1['integer'].apply(to_integer)
```

gives column of integers (`np.int64`).

But if I apply it to this `df2`:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(['1', '', '3'], columns=['integer'])
result = df2['integer'].apply(to_integer)
```

it returns a column of floats (`np.float64`).

Isn't it possible to have a dataframe with integers and `None` at the same time?

I use Python 3.3 and Pandas 0.12.

Comment: as far as a I know, it's not possible to have int `NaN` value in numpy, take a look here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12708807/numpy-integer-nan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are exactly right, it is not possible to have a series of ints and np.nan values.

The way that numpy implements missing values is as np.float64

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/missing_data.html.

The relevant part of the documentation is as follows:

"While pandas supports storing arrays of integer and boolean type, these types are not capable of storing missing data. Until we can switch to using a native NA type in NumPy, we’ve established some “casting rules” when reindexing will cause missing data to be introduced into, say, a Series or DataFrame. Here they are:

```
`data type  Cast to`
`integer    float`
`boolean    object`
`float  no cast`
`object no cast`
```