# How to read binary files in Python using NumPy?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, data-mining

I know how to read binary files in Python using NumPy's `np.fromfile()` function. The issue I'm faced with is that when I do so, the array has exceedingly large numbers of the order of 10^100 or so, with random `nan` and `inf` values.

I need to apply machine learning algorithms to this dataset and I cannot work with this data. I cannot normalise the dataset because of the `nan` values.

I've tried `np.nan_to_num()` but that doesn't seem to work. After doing so, my min and max values range from 3e-38 and 3e+38 respectively, so I could not normalize it.

Is there any way to scale this data down? If not, how should I deal with this?

Thank you.

**EDIT:**

Some context. I'm working on a malware classification problem. My dataset consists of live malware binaries. They are files of the type .exe, .apk etc. My idea is store these binaries as a numpy array, convert to a grayscale image and then perform pattern analysis on it.

Comment: try `pandas` to read the file

Comment: @maxymoo can `pandas` read binary files?

Comment: what do you mean "binary file"? can you add a sample of the file to your post?

Comment: What kinds of numbers do you expect?  Have you tried specifying the `dtype` parameter?  It's using the default `float`.

Comment: OK, the values don't represent real numbers; no wonder the float version looks odd.  Try a dtype like `np.uint8`, which represents each byte as number between 0 and 255.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you want to make an image out of a binary file, you need to read it in as integer, not float.  Currently, the most common format for images is unsigned 8-bit integers.

As an example, let's make an image out of the first 10,000 bytes of /bin/bash:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import cv2
>>> xbash = np.fromfile('/bin/bash', dtype='uint8')
>>> xbash.shape
(1086744,)
>>> cv2.imwrite('bash1.png', xbash[:10000].reshape(100,100))
```

In the above, we used the OpenCV library to write the integers to a PNG file.  Any of several other imaging libraries could have been used.

This what the first 10,000 bytes of `bash` "looks" like:

[image]

Comment: This worked! I was reading the binary files as floats, which caused the error. I read it as uint8 and it worked fine. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT 2**

- Refer this answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/11548224/6633975

  It states: `NaN` can't be stored in an integer array. This is a known
  limitation of pandas at the moment; I have been waiting for progress
  to be made with NA values in NumPy (similar to NAs in R), but it will
  be at least 6 months to a year before NumPy gets these features, it
  seems:

  source:
  http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/gotchas.html#support-for-integer-na

[Numpy integer nan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12708807/numpy-integer-nan)
Accepted answer states:`NaN` can't be stored in an integer array. A `nan` is a special value for float arrays **only**.
       There are talks about introducing a special bit that would allow    non-float arrays to store what in practice would correspond to a    `nan`, but so far (2012/10), it's only talks.
       In the meantime, you may want to consider the    [`numpy.ma`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.html)    package: instead of picking an invalid integer like -99999, you could    use the special `numpy.ma.masked` value to represent an invalid    value.

```
a = np.ma.array([1,2,3,4,5], dtype=int)
a[1] = np.ma.masked
masked_array(data = [1 -- 3 4 5],
             mask = [False  True False False False],
       fill_value = 999999)
```

**EDIT 1**

To read binary file:

1. Read the binary file content like this:

   ```
   with open(fileName, mode='rb') as file: # b is important -> binary
       fileContent = file.read()
   ```

   After that you can "unpack" binary data using [struct.unpack](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html#struct.unpack)
2. If you are using `np.fromfile()` function:

   [`numpy.fromfile`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromfile.html),
   which can read data from both text and binary files. You would first
   construct a data type, which represents your file format, using
   [`numpy.dtype`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.html),
   and then read this type from file using `numpy.fromfile`.