# pandas generates a new column based on values from another column considering duplicates

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am working on a `dataframe` which has a column that each value is a list, now I want to derive a new column which only considers list whose size is greater than 1, assigns a unique integer to the corresponding row as id. If elements in two lists are the same but with a different order, the two lists should be assigned the same id. A sample `dataframe` is like,

```
document_no_list    cluster_id
[1,2,3]             1
[3,2,1]             1
[4,5,6,7]           2
[8]                 0
[9,10]              3
[10,9]              3
```

column `cluster_id` only considers the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 5th and 6th row, each of which has a size greater than 1, and assigns a unique integer id to its corresponding cell in the column, also `[1,2,3]`, `[3,2,1]` and `[9,10]`, `[10,9]` should be assigned the same `cluster_id`.

I was asking a similar question without considering duplicates list values, at

[pandas how to derived values for a new column base on another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46937501/pandas-how-to-derived-values-for-a-new-column-base-on-another-column)

I am wondering how to do that in pandas.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to assign a column with the list lengths, and another column with the lists <s>as set objects</s> sorted:

```
df['list_len'] = df.document_no_list.apply(len)
df['list_sorted'] = df.document_no_list.apply(sorted)
```

Then you need to assign the `cluster_id` for each <s>set</s> sorted list:

```
ids = df.loc[df.list_len > 1, ['list_sorted']].drop_duplicates()
ids['cluster_id'] = range(1,len(ids)+1)
```

Left join this onto the original dataframe, and fill whatever that hasn't been joined (the singletons) with zeros:

```
df.merge(ids, how = 'left').fillna({'cluster_id':0})
```

Comment: `TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't actually try running that code. Apparently pandas runs into trouble dealing with sets, so you could sort the lists instead and compare them.