# Unable to insert NA's in numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I was working on this piece of code and was stuck here.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(10)
a[7:] = np.nan
```

By theory, it should insert missing values starting from index 7 until the end of the array. However, when I ran the code, some random values are inserted into the array instead of NA's.

Can someone explain what happened here and how should I insert missing values intentionally into numpy arrays?

Comment: `how should I insert missing values intentionally into numpy arrays` - Change dtype to float.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Numpy integer nan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12708807/numpy-integer-nan)

Answer (score 1):

Not-a-number (NA) is a special type of floating point number. By default, `np.arange()` creates an array of type `int`. Casting this to `float` should allow you to add NA's:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(10).astype(float)
a[7:] = np.nan
```