# Replace a certain value with np.nan or NA or nan in Numpy in python

Tags: python, numpy, nan, na

I've got a numpy array that contains data, but I want to replace some certain values with NA. I don't want to deal with masked data so I don't mask it. Is this possible?

My data is a numpy array with data type uint16:

```
array([[[1, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 1],
        ...,
        [1, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 1]]], dtype=uint16)
```

I want to replace those "1"s with NA values, I have used the code below, but I'm getting this error:

```
aa [aa == 1] = np.nan
ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer
```

Comment: Please include a small sample input and the expected output. What do you me mean by "replace some certain values with NA"?

Comment: Please check the edited post.

Comment: try creating it with np.float instead of unit16

Comment: The edited post still doesn't contain an example output of what you expect.

Answer (score 2):

`type(np.nan)` returns `<class 'float'>`.

You need your array to be of `float` type.

See: [Numpy integer nan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12708807/numpy-integer-nan)

Answer (score 1):

You try to put NaN values into an array of type `uint16` which is a type that doesn't know a NaN value.  Try the same with `float32` instead and it will work.