# How do I encode NaN values in xarray / zarr with integer dtype?

Tags: encoding, python-xarray, zarr

I have a large xarray DataArray containing NaNs and want to save it with zarr. I want to minimize the file size and am OK with losing a few bits of precision - 16 bits ought to be OK.
I tried using `numcodecs.FixedScaleOffset(astype='u2')` filter but this stores all NaNs as zero. Since the data also contains zeros as valid values, this is not very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Often you can get away with using the max int as your NaN placeholder. So, if you subclass `FixedScaleOffset`:

```
import numpy as np
from numcodecs import FixedScaleOffset
from numcodecs.compat import ensure_ndarray, ndarray_copy
from numcodecs.registry import register_codec


class FixedScaleOffsetNaN(FixedScaleOffset):
    """
    NaN version of FixedScaleOffset
    """

    codec_id = "fixedscaleoffsetnan"

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.missing_int = np.iinfo(self.astype).max

    def encode(self, buf):

        # normalise input
        arr = ensure_ndarray(buf).view(self.dtype)

        # flatten to simplify implementation
        arr = arr.reshape(-1, order="A")

        # compute scale offset
        enc = (arr - self.offset) * self.scale

        # round to nearest integer
        enc = np.around(enc)

        # convert dtype
        enc = np.where(
            np.isnan(arr), self.missing_int, enc.astype(self.astype, copy=False)
        )

        return enc

    def decode(self, buf, out=None):

        # interpret buffer as numpy array
        enc = ensure_ndarray(buf).view(self.astype)

        # flatten to simplify implementation
        enc = enc.reshape(-1, order="A")

        # decode scale offset
        dec = (enc / self.scale) + self.offset

        # convert dtype
        dec = np.where(
            enc == self.missing_int, np.nan, dec.astype(self.dtype, copy=False)
        )

        # handle output
        return ndarray_copy(dec, out)

register_codec(FixedScaleOffsetNaN)
```

The key bits are the `np.where` lines.

```
> compressor = FixedScaleOffsetNaN(0, 1e4, dtype="f8", astype="u2")
> x = np.array([0.0, 0.1, 0.11, 0.111, 0.1111, 0.11111, 1.0, 1.5, np.nan])
> y = compressor.encode(x)
[    0  1000  1100  1110  1111  1111 10000 15000 65535]
> z = compressor.decode(y)
[0.     0.1    0.11   0.111  0.1111 0.1111 1.     1.5       nan]
```

Note this is untested and likely not well thought out. I'm just a climatologist.

Answer (score 0):

NumPy's `u2` (a.k.a. `uint16`) does not support NaN values (please this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12716271/3877089)). Zarr is merely reflecting NumPy's behavior.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work with `numcodecs.Quantize`, but the xarray `encoding` parameters can specify `_FillValue`:

```py
dataset.to_zarr(store, encoding={'<array-name>': {'dtype': 'uint16', '_FillValue': 65535}})
```

See https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/io.html#writing-encoded-data