# Numpy : check for integer NaN

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, nan

I need to have a table with columns of different datatypes (float or integer).

I use the dtype to define them :

```
import numpy as np

# define array
datadef=[ ('i', '<i4'), ('f', '<f8'), ('g', '<f8'), ('j', '<i4') ]
arr = np.full((4,), np.nan, dtype=datadef) 

# fill array with data
arr['i'] = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
arr['f'] = np.array([1.3333333333, np.nan, 2.6666666666666666, 5.0])
arr['g'] = np.array([2.77777777777, 5.4, 3.4, np.nan])
# nothing for 'j'
print arr
```

Output :

```
[(1,  1.33333333,  2.77777778, -2147483648)
 (2,         nan,  5.4       , -2147483648)
 (3,  2.66666667,  3.4       , -2147483648)
 (4,  5.        ,         nan, -2147483648)]
```

The `NaN` values of the last column has been transformed into `-2147483648`, no problem with that so far.

But now I am not able to check if the values are indeed NaN in my array :

```
row = arr[1]
print np.isnan(row) # TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

And on a single cell it seems like the `NaN` information is lost and the `-2147483648` is considered as a "classic number" :

```
print row # (2,  nan,  5.4, -2147483648)
print np.isnan(row[0]) # False, OK
print np.isnan(row[1]) # True, OK
print np.isnan(row[3]) # False, expected True
```

Is there an easy way to check for `NaN` on integers in this situation ?

Comment: There is no NaN for integer in numpy: see e.g.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12708807/numpy-integer-nan . But there seems to be an extension in pandas : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11548005/numpy-or-pandas-keeping-array-type-as-integer-while-having-a-nan-value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`np.nan` is float and not an integer. You either have to change your dtype for last column or use a different structure to store your nan as integer.

```
datadef=[ ('i', '<i4'), ('f', '<f8'), ('g', '<f8'), ('j', '<f4') ]
arr = np.full((4,), np.nan, dtype=datadef) 

# fill array with data
arr['i'] = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
arr['f'] = np.array([1.3333333333, np.nan, 2.6666666666666666, 5.0])
arr['g'] = np.array([2.77777777777, 5.4, 3.4, np.nan])
# nothing for 'j'
```

Now try printing np.isnan statement:

```
print(np.isnan(arr[1][3]))

True
```