# How to convert object columns to int and float columns without converting datetime columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am loading the table into pandas as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_excel(file.xlsx,dtype=object)
A   B         C        D
1   2.0   1-02-1997   sam
Nan 2.3   3-08-1997   ram
2   nan   2-03-1997   pam
```

then I am replacing NaN Value

```
df=df.fillna(method='ffill')
```

then I am converting columns to int and float using

```
for c in df.columns:
   df[c]=pd.to_numeric(df[c],error='ignore')
```

but this will convert datetime columns also into the `int/float`.
Is there any way to restrict datetime conversion to `int/float`?

Comment: For specific columns try `df['col'] = df['col'].astype('int')` or `df['col'] = df['col'].astype(int)`. You don't need to iterate over.

Comment: but he wants more then one columns to be converted , right?

Comment: @adir abargil yes

Comment: you cant convert nan values to int....

Comment: @adirabargil Question has motioned `df=df.fillna(method='ffill')` so I assumed he/she might have already dealt with Null values.

Comment: the fillna didnt convert the first column if it treated it like int

Answer (score 0):

If the datetime columns are already of type datetime, you could only try to convert object columns.

Edit: first convert columns to datetime

```py
# first convert objects to datetime if possible
df = df.apply(pd.to_datetime, errors='ignore')

# then convert remaining objects to numeric
columns = df.columns[df.dtypes=='object']
df[columns] = df[columns].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='ignore')
```

Comment: I am loading all the columns as an object so the above one does not works in the above question.

Comment: You could add a prior step to first convert objects to datetime. Answered edited to show this.

Comment: actually your solution convert all the int /float columns to datetime columns

Comment: Do you know the format of datetime columns? 
```df.apply(pd.to_datetime, errors='ignore', format='%m-%d-%Y')```

Comment: Actually, if just columns type change into DateTime that enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`astype()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) for setting types.
For specific columns (if you have dealt with Null values already and have less no of columns present) try

```
df['col'] = df['col'].astype('int')
```

or

```
df['col'] = df['col'].astype(int)
```

Answer (score 0):

first here is a sample of your dataframe :

```
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO('''A   B         C        D
1   2.0   1-02-1997   sam
Nan 2.3   3-08-1997   ram
2   nan   2-03-1997   pam'''),sep=r'\s+')
df=df.fillna(method='ffill')
df
>>> A   B   C   D
0   1   2.0 1-02-1997   sam
1   Nan 2.3 3-08-1997   ram
2   2   2.3 2-03-1997   pam
```

you can just indicate the error with a `try .. except` statment:

```
def to_numeric(col):
    try:
        return pd.to_numeric(col,error='ignore')
    except:
        return col
    
for c in df.columns:
   df[c]= to_numeric(df[c])

list(map(str,df.dtypes))
>>>['object', 'float64', 'object', 'object']
```

note that column A cant turn into int and it stays 'object' so my suggestion is to turn evetithing to float if fails...

my implementation:

```
def to_numeric(col):
    try:
        return pd.to_numeric(col,error='ignore')
    except:
        try:
            return col.astype(float)
        except:
            return col
    
for c in df.columns:
   df[c]= to_numeric(df[c])

list(map(str,df.dtypes))
>>>['float64', 'float64', 'object', 'object']
```

```
df = df.ffill()
>>> A   B   C   D
0   1.0 2.0 1-02-1997   sam
1   1.0 2.3 3-08-1997   ram
2   2.0 2.3 2-03-1997   pam
```

Comment: you are not converting columns D into Datetime and also converting A into float instead of int.

Comment: I am converting a to float because it cannot be int (it has nans... look at this 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12716271/8893827 ) it seems that you are requiring more then what you asked for... so please specify what exacly your expected output and it will be easier to fit your needs.. although i think you should figure it out by yourself from all this various of awesome answers people gave to you