# Pandas None series has 0

Tags: python, pandas

I want to generate a pandas series with null values, with int type. I use this:

```py
import pandas as pd
pd.Series(None, index=[1, 2, 3], dtype=int)
```

And it returns

```py
1    0
2    0
3    0
dtype: int64
```

What can I do for it to return a series whose values are null?

Answer (score 3):

Use `Int64` for [`nullable integer type`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/integer_na.html):

```
s = pd.Series(None, index=[1, 2, 3], dtype='Int64')
print (s)
1    <NA>
2    <NA>
3    <NA>
dtype: Int64
```

---

```
s = pd.Series(np.nan, index=[1, 2, 3], dtype=int)
print (s)
1   NaN
2   NaN
3   NaN
dtype: float64 <- casting to float
```

Comment: My main issue is that I'm trying to create series from the type of a variable: ```import pandas as pd; a = 2; type_out = type(a); pd.Series(None, index=[1, 2, 3], dtype=type_out)```

Comment: And I don't know how can I go from int to int64, float to float64, and all the other combinations

Comment: @DavidMasip - It is not possible `type=int` and `None` or `NaN`

Comment: @DavidMasip - only possible some default value, like `0` instead `None`

Comment: And why is this not good? ```pd.Series(np.nan, index=[1, 2, 3], dtype=int)```

Comment: @DavidMasip - because it failed returning `int`.

Comment: @DavidMasip - it return floats

Comment: This post is relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12708807/numpy-integer-nan